# Angular 2 routing show does not work when breaking it down in modules

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am getting an error saying it cannot find my module.

```
ERROR in ./src/app/userManagement/userManagement.routing.ts
    Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './unlockUserID/unlockUserId.module' in src/app/userManagement'
     @ ./src/app/userManagement/userManagement.routing.ts 9:43-94
```

I need to do it this way to make to more modular and it is a single page application. You like on a menu, it drops on in a tree format and when you click the desired tab a component is rendered on that page.

```
src--
     --app
       --userManagement
          --unlockedUserId
            --unlockUserId.component.html
            --unlockUserId.css
            --unlockeUserID.module.ts
            --unlockUser.routing.ts
       --userManagement.module.ts
       --userManagement.routing.ts
```

Inside the directory `userManagement/unlockUserId/unlockUserID.Routing.ts` I have the following:

```
import {RouterModule, Routes} from "@angular/router";
import {unlockUserIdcomponent} from "./unlockUserID.component";
import {NgModule} from "@angular/core";

const routes: Routes = [{
    path: '',
    component: unlockUserIdcomponent,
    data: {pageTitle: 'Unlock User Id'}
}];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule],
    providers: []
})
export class UnlockUserIdModule { }
```

Which I import into my `userManagement/unlockUserId/unlockUserID.module.ts`

```
import {SmartadminModule} from "../../shared/smartadmin.module";
import {CommonModule} from "@angular/common";
import {NgModule} from "@angular/core";

import {unlockUserIdcomponent} from "./unlockUserID.component";


@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        SmartadminModule,
        UnlockUserIdModule
    ],
    declarations: [unlockUserIdcomponent]
})
export class UnlockUserIdModule { }
```

Then The parent module and routing module come in and are used like this:

`userManagement/userManagement.routing.ts`

```
import {RouterModule, Routes} from "@angular/router";

export const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '', redirectTo: 'unlockUserID', pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    {
        path: 'unlockUserID',
        loadChildren: ()=> System.import('./unlockUserID/unlockUserId.module')
            .then((imports: any)=> imports.UnlockUserIdModule)
    }
];

export const routing = RouterModule.forChild(routes);
```

When again is imported into `userManagement.module.ts`

```
import {SmartadminModule} from "../shared/smartadmin.module";
import {NgModule} from "@angular/core";
import {routing} from "./userManagement.routing";

@NgModule({

    imports: [
        SmartadminModule,
        routing
    ],
    providers: [],
})
export class UserManagementModule {

}
```

Now in the main router in the app I do the following to link it all together:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: MainLayoutComponent,
        data: {pageTitle: 'Home'},
        children: [
            {
                path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full'
            },
            {
                path: 'userManagement',
                loadChildren: 'app/userManagement/userManagement.module#UserManagementModule',
                data: {pageTitle: 'UserManagement'}
            },

            {path: 'home', loadChildren: 'app/+home/home.module#HomeModule', data: {pageTitle: 'Home'}},
        ]
    },

    {path: '**', redirectTo: 'home'}

];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {useHash: true});
```

However I am getting an error saying:

```
ERROR in ./src/app/userManagement/userManagement.routing.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './unlockUserID/unlockUserId.module' in src/app/userManagement'
 @ ./src/app/userManagement/userManagement.routing.ts 9:43-94
```

Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you have twise the same class name UnlockUserIdModule

Comment: maybe just a typo, but you listed --unlock`e`UserID.module.ts in your file map. should be `--unlockUserID.module.ts`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most major issue I see is that you have two `UnlockUserIdModule`s

your route should be

```
import {RouterModule, Routes} from "@angular/router";
import {ModuleWithProviders } from "@angular/core";

import {unlockUserIdcomponent} from "./unlockUserID.component";

const unlockUserRoutes: Routes = [{
    path: '',
    component: unlockUserIdcomponent,
    data: {pageTitle: 'Unlock User Id'}
}];

export const unlockUserRouting: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forChild(unlockUserRoutes);
```

then in your module:

```
import {CommonModule} from "@angular/common";
import {NgModule} from "@angular/core";

import {SmartadminModule} from "../../shared/smartadmin.module";
import {unlockUserIdcomponent} from "./unlockUserID.component";
import { unlockUserRouting } from './unlockUser.routing';


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    SmartadminModule,
    unlockUserRouting
  ],
  declarations: [unlockUserIdcomponent]
})
export class UnlockUserIdModule { }
```

also in general, for readability it's best to group your imports by where they a re coming from (e.g all @angular imports at the top, then vendor, then your code imports)

Answer (score 1):

I see several problems in your snippets:

1. `UnlockUserIdModule` imports itself in `imports` section.
   That could be a reason of undefined module/cycle error/stack overflow
2. Are you loading app via SystemJS or via webpack with plugins to replace last one? Please, try to replace module path to absolute:

   `userManagement.routing.ts:`

   `loadChildren: 'app/userManagement/unlockedUserId/unlockUserID.module#UnlockUserIdModule'`
3. typo in filename - `unlockeUserID.module.ts`

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to angular (and StackOverflow) but perhaps I can help you.

For your main route (app.routing.js) you can specify it as:

```
import {..} from ...
const APP_ROUTES: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/yourpath', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'yourpath', component: SomeComponent }, 
    { path: 'home', component: ComponentWithChildren, children: CHILDREN_ROUTES }, //This specifies the child routes called CHILDREN_ROUTES 

];

export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(APP_ROUTES);
```

Then you can specify your child routes (in your case, you called it `unlockUserId`).

The example below shows the children of the `home` path.

```
import {...} from ...
export const CHILDREN_ROUTES : Routes = [
    { path: '', component: unlockUserId}, //If the child route is empty, redirect to the "unlockUserIdcomponent" path below
    { path: 'unlockUserId', component: unlockUserIdcomponent}
];
```

The `CHILDREN_ROUTES` can also have their own children, just like the `APP_ROUTES` (and so on...).

I hope this answered your question.

Comment: No this will not work for what I am trying to do and need to do. Under `app` I have several directories. Each Directory will have several children. In each directory it will have a `module.ts` and `routing.ts`. In the main `app.routing` is when they will all become known. This is a one page app and components will render based on what is selected from a menu bar. The `menu bar` is much like a tree, you select `User Management` it expands and on of the options is `UnlockUserId` select it and the component is rendered on that page.

Comment: Please see my updated post. I redid the whole thing.